# How to create a column in Microstrategy that contains the sum of another column

Tags: microstrategy

I want to make a column that contains only the value $18,432,807 so I can find the percentage that that months profit is of the total profit.

Comment: could you not just create a derived element with a calculation = $18,432,807 or whatever?

Answer (score 1):

If you right-click on a metric column, you should be able to choose new -> metric. You'll then be prompted to provide a formula, where you can use other metrics also in the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as loco suggested, or you can create another metric at Year level and then a metric with does OriginalMetric/YearMetric